# How do I find an object by object inside a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I'm storing websocket connections inside an array. These are objects. And I'd like to remove a connection from the array when the connection is closed.

Is there any way I can find which connection object matches the closing connection and unset it?

I don't think `indexOf` works, right? Because the value is an object...

.........................................

here's some code

```
var connections = [];

websocketServer.on('request', function(request) {
  var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

  connection.on('message', function(message){
    if(message.type !== 'utf8')
      return;

    var msg = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);

    if(msg.txt == 'something'){
      connections.push(connection);
    }

  });

  connection.on('close', function(connection) {
    // here remove connection object from connections array

  });
});
```

Comment: What is the criteria to match the objects?

Comment: if object1 == object2 ... but i need to somehow match the exact instance

Comment: Then `indexOf` itself should work.

Comment: indexOf can find a specific instance of the object inside an array that contains multiple objects of the same type?

Comment: @thelolcat are you saying you want to look through the array to find objects with a closed connection or you have an object whose connection is known to be closed -- if so, how?

Comment: @thelolcat if you have a reference the object in question, `indexOf` will work.  A similar object will not match with `indexOf`, though: http://jsfiddle.net/YAg3d/1/

Comment: Do you have reference to the object of the connection that has been closed? or do you need to determine from the array if they got closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `indexOf` then `splice`

```
var index = connections.indexOf(connection);
if(~index) connections.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: You can just do `~index` in an `if`.

Comment: @elclanrs meant to do that :D

Answer (score 0):

Use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) and call `_.isEqual(object, other);`

**Underscore** is a utility-belt library for JavaScript that provides a lot of the functional programming support that you would expect in Prototype.js (or Ruby), but without extending any of the built-in JavaScript objects. It's the tie to go along with jQuery's tux, and Backbone.js's suspenders.